# Ubuntu 12.10 virtualhost conflict

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.10

I have 2 sites on my server. One I access via my IP, **x.x.x.x/site1**. The other is a registered domain name, www.mysite.com.

Initially, I had only my **/etc/apache/sites-available/default** file available but when I tried loading either of the sites above I just got my **/var/www/index.html** output.

I included a new virtualhost for mysite.com with the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mysite>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Mysite.com only loads when default is disabled but then, **x.x.x.x/site1** doesn't.

So, I enable the default virtualhost which has the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Now, **x.x.x.x/site1** works but **mysite.com** does not - instead it loads the **/var/www/index.html** page.

I'm confused about what the issue is. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a virtual domain to work it needs to know what host to map to. In your http request for the browser it sets a Host header like

```
Host: mysite.com
```

So apache will read that to figure out what vhost entry to use. You need to add something like

```
ServerName mysite.com www.mysite.com
```

To the mysite.com virtual host in the `<VirtualHost *:80>`